# Selecting prices from database to radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a form here using `php` but I'm stuck!
I have made a form with all types of `food` courses assigned to radio buttons :

```
<form action="proberen.php" method="post">

<label>Klantnummer</label>
<input type="text" name="txtklantnr" /><br/>

<label>Voornaam</label>
<input type="text" name="txtfname" /><br/>

<label>Achternaam</label>
<input type="text" name="txtlname" /><br/>

<br/>
<br/>
---------------------
<br/>
Menu
<br/>
---------------------
<br/>
<br/>
<label>first dish</label><br/><br/>

<label>Soup</label>
<input type="radio" name="txtvoor"  checked="checked" value="soup" />
<label>8 euro</label><br/>

<label>Slaatje</label>
<input type="radio" name="txtvoor" value="sla"  />
<label>6 euro</label><br/><br/>

<label>main dish</label><br/><br/>

<label>Kip met Friet</label>
<input type="radio" name="txthoofd"  checked="checked" value="kip" />
<label>12euro</label><br/>

<label>Worst met Patat</label>
<input type="radio" name="txthoofd" value="worst" />
<label>10euro</label><br/><br/>

<label>Dessert</label><br/><br/>

<label>Ijs</label>
<input type="radio" name="txtna"  checked="checked" value="ijs" />
<label>4euro</label><br/>

<label>Taart</label>
<input type="radio" name="txtna" value="taart" />
<label>5 euro</label><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Bereken Totaal" />

</form>
```

I created a database with all the receppies and a database with all the prices.
Here is my php :

```
<?php
$fldklantnr = $_POST["txtklantnr"];

$fldvnaam = $_POST["txtfname"];
$fldanaam = $_POST["txtlname"];

$fldvoor = $_POST["txtvoor"];
$fldhoofd = $_POST["txthoofd"];
$fldna = $_POST["txtna"];

$db = MySql_connect("localhost","root","root");
Mysql_select_db("menutest",$db);

$result=("select * from tblmenu where fldvoor='$fldvoor'");
$resultb=("select * from tblmenu where fldhoofd='$fldhoofd'");
$resultc=("select * from tblmenu where fldna='$fldna'");

$fldtotaal = $resultd + $resulte+$resultf;


    echo "Beste $fldvnaam $fldanaam.<br/>U heeft het volgende besteld:<br/>";
    echo " $fldvoor <br/>"; 
    echo " $fldhoofd <br/>" ;
    echo " $fldna <br/>" ;
    echo "Het totaal bedrag is $fldtotaal euro. <br/>Bedankt voor uw bestelling.";

$sql="insert into tblmenu values('$fldklantnr','$fldvnaam','$fldanaam','$fldvoor','$fldhoofd','$fldna','$fldtotaal')";

MySql_query($sql,$db);

?>
```

Now I want to calculate the sum of the ordered menu : the prices are in my `tblprijzen` and I tried something like this :

```
if ($result==soup){
    $resultd=("select *from tblprijs where fldsoup='fldsoup'");
}
else{
    $resultd=("select *from tblprijs where fldslaatje='fldslaatje'");
}

if ($resultb==kip){
    $resulte=("select *from tblprijs where fldkip='fldkip'");
}
else{
    $resulte=("select *from tblprijs where fldworst='fldworst'");
}

if ($resultc==ijs){
    $resultf=("select from tblprijs where fldijs='fldijs'");
}
else{
    $resultf=("select from tblprijs where fldtaart='fldtaart'");
}

$totaal = $resultd + $resulte + $resultf;
```

But it doesn't do a thing :(

Trying to make this work for over 2 days, I 'll be glad if I pass that exam tomorrow :)

Comment: What does "does not do a thing" mean? You get a blank page or some error message? Do you get an error in the log files? Does the universe implode?

Comment: You don't expect that line: `$result=("select * from tblmenu where fldvoor='$fldvoor'");` to retrieve something from the database, do you? This just defines a string.

Comment: Well I get this : 

Beste Tom dubois.
U heeft het volgende besteld:
soup 
kip 
ijs 
Het totaal bedrag is 0 euro. 
Bedankt voor uw bestelling.

But I want " Het totaal bedrag is 0 euro.  " 

not to be 0 but the total some of all ordered courses

Comment: So my main question is : how can I get the right prices so I can calculate the total and display that in an echo .. and yes , I feel like imploding ^^

Comment: Look at my second comment. You understood what I wrote? You compute `$fldtotaal = $resultd + $resulte+$resultf;`, but these three vars are just strings. What is the result of adding three strings? You need to _use_ your database connection $db and to run queries in it and to retrieve the results bevor you can use them. So first step: answer to my second comment above.

Comment: Well in that case I have to answer : yes , I thought I could do it like that :( so how would you do it ? you could make my day :) Everything in php just sounds like chaos to me..

Comment: Sorry, but it is 'back to start' for you. You did not understand how to use a database from within code. I suggest you take out those simple examples again about php & mysql and try to understand the flow using these commands: open a database connection (you do that, great!), prepare a query (well, you do that in a primitive way, that is fine for now), run that query (you don't do that at all, take a look at `mysql_query`). Next you have to retrieve the results of queries you ran (`mysql_fetch` and so on) and _then_, only then you can start computing with the values you retrieved.

Comment: ok thx 4 the advice anyway ! Have a nice day !!

Comment: Good luck for your exams... Loads of things to learn and understand you you today...

Comment: Please note that the [`mysql_` family](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) of functions is deprecated and that you should use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.